# Need help understanding a derivation of "witnesses" for a Landau bound

Tags: landau-notation, didactics

So here's an excerpt from *Foundations of Computer Science* by Alfred Aho and Jeffrey Ullman[1]. I've also found basically the same material in a few other places, and also in my discrete math textbook, but this is clearest one I've seen:

> **Example 3.2.** Suppose we have a program whose running time is $T(0) = 1$, $T(1) = 4$, $T(2) = 9$, and in general $T(n) = (n + 1)^2$. We can say that $T(n)$ is $O(n^2)$, or that $T(n)$ is *quadratic*, because we can choose witnesses $n_{0} = 1$ and $c = 4$. We then need to prove that $(n + 1)^2 \leq 4n^2$, provided $n \leq 1$. In proof, expand $(n + 1)^2$ as $n^2 + 2n + 1$. As long as $n \leq 1$, we know that $n \leq n^2$ and $1 \leq n^2$. Thus $n^2 + 2n + 1 \leq n^2 + 2n^2 + n^2 = 4n^2$.

Even so, I get lost where it says:

$$
n^2 + 2n + 1 \leq n^2 + 2n^2 + n^2
$$

I get that it's *true*, but it seems arbitrary. How/why did the expression get modified on the right side of the $\leq$ like it did? Couldn't they also have done this?

$$
n^2 + 2n + 1 \leq 4n^2 + 0 + 0
$$

Specifically, what rule did they apply to transform the expression $n^2 + 2n + 1$ into $n^2 + 2n^2 + n^2$?

---

1. http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/focs.html

Answer (score 4):

They want to end up with ​ constant * n<sup>2</sup> ​ on the very-right.

They applied "make each term a constant times n<sup>2</sup>".

Comment: Why did they do it in that particular way? Couldn't they just as easily have done $n^2 + 2n + 1 \leq 4n^2 + 0n^2 + 0n^2$ ?

Comment: They'd have to _show_ that inequality, which would involve what they actually did. ​ ​

Answer (score 4):

Claim:

$$ n^2 + 2n + 1 \le 4n^2$$

we know it is true, but we still need to prove it.

One option, is to shift sides, getting $3n^2-2n+1 \ge 0$, and solving this equation shows it holds for any $n\ge 1$. But this is cumbersome.

What else can we do? We can take a crude bound for each term.
For instance, $n^2 \le n^2$, $2n \le 2n^2$, and $1\le n^2$ hold **for any $n\ge1$**!
Therefore, it is valid to say that
$$n^2 + 2n + 1 \le n^2 +2n^2 +n^2 \le 4n^2.$$
and it is quite *intuitive* and easy to see, even for the non-expert.

What's wrong with $n^2 + 2n + 1 \le 4n^2 + 0+0$?
*Technically*, nothing is wrong - this is a valid claim for any $n\ge 1$.
However **intuitively** this derivation is misleading: it suggests that we bound the three terms one by one, which "suggests" the **incorrect** derivation of $n^2 \le 4n^2$; $2n \le 0$; and $1\le 0$.

Bottom-line: since Aho-Ullman is meant for students, it tries to give simple explanations that any reader can easily verify in the most simple way, even if it is longer and less "direct".

---

(actually this is not a CS question, but math. Hmpf.).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. So they had to transform the expression $4n^2$ into an equivalent expression $n^2 + 2n^2 + n^2$ in order to have an explicit term-for-term comparison to $n^2 + 2n + 1$.